# BeautifulSoup or requests not reading some section of a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to web scraping and having some trouble getting data from a webpage.

I'm trying to read this web page: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic?month=7&year=2018

and trying to get the wind speed data through a div element with the class: wstext, but for some reason the page that requests library gets through the internet does not contain this particular class and some of its ancestors.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import numpy as np

wind = np.random.rand(120)
dailyWindRecord = np.random.rand(30,4)

html = requests.get('https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic?month=7&year=2018')

print(html.text)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html5lib')

print(soup.prettify)

windList = soup.findAll('div')
print(windList)
```

I've tried printing the html data requests read directly and the after parsing it through beautifulsoup to see if the html data contained that class but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The web page is probably using some JavaScript to load further data.

Comment: Have you tried to say `wget`/`curl` this page and than run your script on files?

Comment: I have no problem with  `curl https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic\?month\=7\&year\=2018 > result.html` And I see `var data` - json that contains all data.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, the div class I'm looking for is under a div id that I can find by using beautifulsoup but the descendants of that particular class are missing for some reason. I didn't know Javascript could be used to add or remove html elements, but reading it out aloud, it does make sense.

So when inspecting a webpage, how do you know if an html element is being loaded through JS or nto

Comment: @AlexYu, could you post the entire solution please, I'm not that familiar with curl so I'd have an easier time understanding the code.

Comment: @AlexYu, I actually wouldn't mind seeing your solution too. I'm trying to learn the curl method as well.

Comment: I posted my "kinda solution", I ommitted obvious part with `str.find`, `json.load`, etc

Comment: Hm. I look again at `data` in my solution and `table.iloc[:,4]` in @chitown88 solution. I see that `data` contains temperature and `table.iloc[:,4]` returns wind speed. Did we really solved the OP problem?

Comment: @AlexYu, wind speed is in your solution. It's under the key `detail`. I'll post the pic below for you to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas can do the work for you rather than using bs4 or requests:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

wind = np.random.rand(120)
dailyWindRecord = np.random.rand(30,4)

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic?month=7&year=2018'

tables = pd.read_html(url)

table = tables[1]

print (table.iloc[:,4])
```

**Output:**

```
print (table.iloc[:,4])
0       3 mph
1     No wind
2     No wind
3     No wind
4     No wind
5     No wind
6     No wind
7       3 mph
8       5 mph
9       6 mph
10      5 mph
11      5 mph
12      6 mph
13      5 mph
14    No wind
15      3 mph
16    No wind
17    No wind
18    No wind
19    No wind
20      5 mph
21    No wind
22      6 mph
23      6 mph
24      5 mph
25      6 mph
26      7 mph
27      7 mph
28      7 mph
29      3 mph
30      3 mph
31      3 mph
32      3 mph
33    No wind
34      3 mph
35      3 mph
36    No wind
37    No wind
38        NaN
Name: (Unnamed: 4_level_0, Wind), dtype: object
```

**Option 2:**

You can find and pull the json structure in the html and then work with that. When I tried that though, it has the data spanned out for the month, rather than the single day, by the hour:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import bs4
import json

wind = np.random.rand(120)
dailyWindRecord = np.random.rand(30,4)

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic?month=7&year=2018'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
jsonObj = None

for script in scripts:
    if 'var data='  in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text.strip()

        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('var data=')[1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split(';')[0]

        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

for item in jsonObj['detail']:
    date = item['ds']
    wind = item['wind']

    print ('Date: %-40s   Wind: %s' %(date,wind) )
```

**Output:**

```
Date: Sunday, 1 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00         Wind: 0.621
Date: Sunday, 1 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00         Wind: 3.728
Date: Sunday, 1 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00         Wind: 3.107
Date: Sunday, 1 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00         Wind: 3.107
Date: Monday, 2 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00         Wind: 1.864
Date: Monday, 2 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00         Wind: 5.593
Date: Monday, 2 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00         Wind: 8.7
Date: Monday, 2 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00         Wind: 9.943
Date: Tuesday, 3 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 10.564
Date: Tuesday, 3 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 11.185
Date: Tuesday, 3 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 9.943
Date: Tuesday, 3 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 6.214
Date: Wednesday, 4 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 6.836
Date: Wednesday, 4 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 4.971
Date: Wednesday, 4 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Wednesday, 4 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 3.728
Date: Thursday, 5 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 1.864
Date: Thursday, 5 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 1.864
Date: Thursday, 5 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 3.107
Date: Thursday, 5 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 3.107
Date: Friday, 6 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00         Wind: 1.864
Date: Friday, 6 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00         Wind: 6.214
Date: Friday, 6 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00         Wind: 6.836
Date: Friday, 6 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00         Wind: 3.728
Date: Saturday, 7 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 1.243
Date: Saturday, 7 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 2.486
Date: Saturday, 7 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Saturday, 7 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 2.486
Date: Sunday, 8 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00         Wind: 3.107
Date: Sunday, 8 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00         Wind: 6.214
Date: Sunday, 8 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00         Wind: 5.593
Date: Sunday, 8 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00         Wind: 4.35
Date: Monday, 9 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00         Wind: 5.593
Date: Monday, 9 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00         Wind: 5.593
Date: Monday, 9 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00         Wind: 6.214
Date: Monday, 9 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00         Wind: 4.35
Date: Tuesday, 10 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Tuesday, 10 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 8.078
Date: Tuesday, 10 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Tuesday, 10 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 5.593
Date: Wednesday, 11 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00     Wind: 6.214
Date: Wednesday, 11 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00     Wind: 12.428
Date: Wednesday, 11 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00     Wind: 8.078
Date: Wednesday, 11 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00     Wind: 5.593
Date: Thursday, 12 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 4.971
Date: Thursday, 12 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 8.078
Date: Thursday, 12 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 7.457
Date: Thursday, 12 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Friday, 13 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Friday, 13 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 11.807
Date: Friday, 13 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 9.321
Date: Friday, 13 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Saturday, 14 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 4.971
Date: Saturday, 14 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 4.971
Date: Saturday, 14 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Saturday, 14 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Sunday, 15 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 8.7
Date: Sunday, 15 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 8.7
Date: Sunday, 15 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 8.7
Date: Sunday, 15 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Monday, 16 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 4.971
Date: Monday, 16 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 11.185
Date: Monday, 16 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 11.185
Date: Monday, 16 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 8.7
Date: Tuesday, 17 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 7.457
Date: Tuesday, 17 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 8.078
Date: Tuesday, 17 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Tuesday, 17 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 4.971
Date: Wednesday, 18 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00     Wind: 3.728
Date: Wednesday, 18 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00     Wind: 2.486
Date: Wednesday, 18 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00     Wind: 6.214
Date: Wednesday, 18 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00     Wind: 4.971
Date: Thursday, 19 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 4.971
Date: Thursday, 19 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 5.593
Date: Thursday, 19 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Thursday, 19 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 1.864
Date: Friday, 20 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 2.486
Date: Friday, 20 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Friday, 20 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 8.078
Date: Friday, 20 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 3.728
Date: Saturday, 21 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 0.621
Date: Saturday, 21 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 1.243
Date: Saturday, 21 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 2.486
Date: Saturday, 21 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 7.457
Date: Sunday, 22 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 4.971
Date: Sunday, 22 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 6.836
Date: Sunday, 22 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 4.35
Date: Sunday, 22 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 4.35
Date: Monday, 23 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 2.486
Date: Monday, 23 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 6.214
Date: Monday, 23 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 6.836
Date: Monday, 23 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 4.971
Date: Tuesday, 24 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 3.107
Date: Tuesday, 24 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 7.457
Date: Tuesday, 24 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 4.35
Date: Tuesday, 24 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 2.486
Date: Wednesday, 25 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00     Wind: 1.243
Date: Wednesday, 25 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00     Wind: 3.728
Date: Wednesday, 25 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00     Wind: 6.836
Date: Wednesday, 25 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00     Wind: 7.457
Date: Thursday, 26 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 7.457
Date: Thursday, 26 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 9.321
Date: Thursday, 26 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 11.185
Date: Thursday, 26 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 7.457
Date: Friday, 27 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 6.836
Date: Friday, 27 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Friday, 27 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 4.35
Date: Friday, 27 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 4.35
Date: Saturday, 28 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00      Wind: 3.728
Date: Saturday, 28 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00      Wind: 6.214
Date: Saturday, 28 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00      Wind: 1.864
Date: Saturday, 28 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00      Wind: 3.728
Date: Sunday, 29 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 3.107
Date: Sunday, 29 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 6.836
Date: Sunday, 29 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 5.593
Date: Sunday, 29 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 2.486
Date: Monday, 30 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00        Wind: 1.864
Date: Monday, 30 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00        Wind: 3.728
Date: Monday, 30 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00        Wind: 4.971
Date: Monday, 30 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00        Wind: 2.486
Date: Tuesday, 31 July 2018, 00:00 — 06:00       Wind: 1.243
Date: Tuesday, 31 July 2018, 06:00 — 12:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Tuesday, 31 July 2018, 12:00 — 18:00       Wind: 6.836
Date: Tuesday, 31 July 2018, 18:00 — 00:00       Wind: 3.107
```

Here's the breakdown of the json format to get to `wind`

[image]

Comment: Wow! That was unexpected solution! Although OP problem could be solved without pandas - it's a good find

Comment: This actually did the job perfectly, thank you.

So whenever I need to find some table elements, it's better to just use pandas rather than requests or beautifulsoup

Comment: If I see `<table>` tags, I usually try pandas `.read_html()` first. If it can get back relatively what I need, I just go with it, I'd rather do a little work to manipulate a dataframe, than a ton of work iterating through all the table, th, tr, td tags.

Comment: @HamzaWaheed pandas [uses BeautifulSoap](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f75a220ff1e5e027ef2b070430fd7f4490cdcbf0/pandas/io/html.py#L526) under the hood

Comment: Great! I think "Option 2" is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

My exploration and very-very dirty "kind of solution" for problem

## 1. BeautifulSoap is just fine

Look at [pandas solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502070/1168212) - it works just fine.

Look at [pandas source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/html.py#L526) - we see that pandas is using `_BeautifulSoupHtml5LibFrameParser`.

Ergo: BeautifulSoup is fine.

## 2. "Nitty-gritty dirty kinda solution" with curl

Let's try [curl](https://curl.haxx.se):

```
$ curl https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/pakistan/lahore/historic\?month\=7\&year\=2018 > result.html   
$ less result.html
```

What we see here:

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">
var data={"copyright":"Contents are strictly for use by 
timeanddate.com","units": 
{"temp":"°C","prec":"mm","wind":"km\/h","baro":"mbar"},
"temp":        
[{"date":15304047E5,"temp":29},{"date":15304065E5,"temp":29},  
{"date":15304083E5,"temp":29},{"date":15304101E5,"temp":28},
...
```

I suppose it's the data that OP looking for.

## 3. Possible solution

1. Download url in some way or another. `curl`/`wget`/`requests` - everything must be fine
2. From downloaded html extract `var data`. Python `str`-methods must be sufficient
3. `json.loads` this extracted `data`
4. Finish

Beauty in such solution - data cames `as is` without decoding from html `<table>`.

### P.S.

Personaly I like `pandas`-solution.

Because `pandas` is great library itself.

But pandas is not needed to solve this problem.

Comment: ah ok.  That's not too different than what I do sometimes. I'll sometimes pull out the json structure. I just tied it now, but seems the data for that is not hourly on a single day, but rather span of the whole month (see edit to my solution below). Does your method get the hourly for the single day?

Comment: I explored only "beautyfulsoap is not reading some part of page" - I did not even look carefully at data that OP requesting. I like your "Option 2" ... too. Would it be possible I would give you a second plus.